# Browser safe way to open a new window sized to content (not a tab) and bring up the OS's print dialog?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, cross-browser

Normally I would use:

```
window.openDialog();
```

then in that Window's body element's onload event call

```
window.print();
```

But neither seem to be working in Google Chrome?!

What I am trying to do is simply create a print view of a page.

Answer (score 0):

`window.openDialog()` is not cross-browser compatible. It's an extension from `window.open()`, which all major browsers support, so you should use that instead.

See:

- http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/WindowOpenDialogMethod
- http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/WindowOpenMethod

`window.print()` should work though.

Comment: problem is window.open() will open in a new tab on a tabbed browser and print() is doing nothing my GoogleChrome! thanks anyway